# I can't see anything while running Rails server or Node server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, node.js

I'm in a big problem, I can run my Rails or Node servers, but when I look into the browser, Chrome tells me that can't acces into localhost page.

I tried modifying the hosts file in C://Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

I have removed the comments to:
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

But nothing happens, when that lines are in comments Apache works, but not Rails or Node.

I don't have any proxy, I triedd with differents ports, and I don't know what else to do.

I would appreciate any advice

Comment: Are you accessing localhost:3000 for rails ?

Comment: Yes, but I think my problem is that I can't access to localhost, because it doesn't work for Rails, don't even for Node or Apache

Comment: Firefox sends me to google, the same with IE and Bingo.

Comment: What happens if you try to access http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (for rails) ?